# Detecting Multiple Guild IDs - Discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

This code works for sending a DM to a user who joined a guild, but it only executes the first if statement instead of actually checking to see what guild the member joined. I'll get the first DM from the bot whether I join guild1 or guild2.

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    guild1 = client.get_guild(762921541204705321)
    guild2 = client.get_guild(593941391110045697)
    if guild1.id == 762921541204705321:
        await member.create_dm()
        await member.dm_channel.send("Welcome to guild1!")
    elif guild2.id == 593941391110045697:
        await member.create_dm()
        await member.dm_channel.send(f"Welcome to guild2!")
```

Comment: Can you clarify what the issue is? At a glance, the code doesn't seem to be doing anything to check which guild the user is part of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, you are not actually checking the guild that the member is in.
In discord.py (and similar libraries), member objects are not unique to a user, but rather they represent a user's membership in a guild.

With discord.py, the guild is stored in a member as the property "guild":

```
guild_id = member.guild.id
```

You can then compare the member's guild with your other guild ids:

```
if guild_id == 762921541204705321:
    # do stuff
elif guild_id == 1231254125151:
    # do other stuff
```

Comment: That makes more sense. Thanks!